# Scheduled task failing when being deployed by GPO on some PC's

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled a Task Scheduler using GPO (Windows 2012 R2). it failed when triggered by Task Scheduler with below error.

> The operator or administrator has refused the request(0x800710E0)

I have followed below steps also after Google search

1. Checked "**Run whether user logged in or not**"
2. Unchecked "**Start the task only if the computer is on AC power**"

the actual command is

```
Schtasks.exe /Create /SC DAILY /TN Shutdown /TR "C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 0" /ST 21:00:00 /SD 01/01/2015 /RU SYSTEM /RL HIGHEST
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you using GP to distribute this task? GPP? Computer-level or user-level?  How exactly are you utilizing your "actual command"?  I ask because that's a command to create a task, which you wouldn't use AS a task, nor would you use it like that in conjunction with GPP to configure a task.

Comment: Computer Configuration. In the run field, schtasks.exe and in the argument field, everything from /Create .... then start in is "C:\Windows\system32"

Comment: Ok assuming you're using GPP (Group Policy Preferences) to create the scheduled task (as you haven't clarified that yet), why are you telling it to create a task that runs Schtasks to create a task?

Comment: to be honest, it was in my documentation from my predecessor. Not sure why it was done this way.

Comment: we are create a task that runs as "SYSTEM" instead of a Domain account.

Comment: Please edit your question and spell out EXACTLY how you configured the task in GPP including screenshots, etc. (again, IF that's what you're doing, as you still haven't clarified that).  Perhaps transpose the documentation you're trying to use.  As I said, to me it make NO SENSE to make a task that makes another task, so until you can explain if/why that's what you want to do the I'd say that's the problem.

Comment: added pictures to the question

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason (at least not one that you've explained) to make a task (via GPP) that creates a task (via SchTasks).

So just define the Shutdown task directly in GPP.  To do this, in the GPP policy:

- Set "Run" to `shutdown.exe`
- Set "Arguments" to `/s /t 0`